# Как с помощью регулярного выражения preg_match_all разбить строчку на массив из картинок и текста

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст

```
Хочу пить!<img src="/images/upload/3k0tx90veagw88gsgwwoocgk8sg4k8w.png"/>
Хочу,< и пить!`<img src="/images/upload/gidykcwjge0wwcs8ws40kw4040sw44w.png"/>Хочу: есть?
```

Как помощью регулярного выражения `preg_match_all` разбить строчку на массив

```
[0] = Хочу пить!
[1] = <img src="/images/upload/3k0tx90veagw88gsgwwoocgk8sg4k8w.png"/>
[2] = Хочу,< и пить!
[3] = <img src="/images/upload/gidykcwjge0wwcs8ws40kw4040sw44w.png"/>
[4] = Хочу: есть?
```

Условия такие, что в тексте может присутствовать любой символ, и строка может начинаться с текста или картинки и заканчивать текстом или картинкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так проще всего **с данной строкой**:

```
#(^[^<]+)|(<img[^>]+>)|((?<=>).+?(?=<i))|((?<=>).+?$)#isu
```

Проверка работы https://regex101.com/r/Z6ak3S/1

Answer (score 0):

Первое чтобы я сделал, так это вытащил картинки:

```
$text = 'Хочу пить!<img src="/images/upload/3k0tx90veagw88gsgwwoocgk8sg4k8w.png"/>Хочу,< и пить!<img src="/images/upload/gidykcwjge0wwcs8ws40kw4040sw44w.png"/>Хочу: есть?';
preg_match_all( '/(\<img.+\/\>)/', $text, $img );
```

Второе: заменил бы картинки на разделители

```
for($i=1, $size = sizeof($img); $i < $size; $i++ ){
  $text = str_replace( $img[$i], '||||', $text );
}
```

Третье: создал бы массив текста:

```
$text_arr = explode( '||||', $text);
```

Четвертое: получил бы готовый массив

```
$result = [];
foreach( $text_arr as $key => $value ){
  $result[] = $value;
  $result[] = $img[$key+1];
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

для решения вашей задачи следует использовать [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php)  с сохранением разделителей, а не `preg_match`. Вы же "разбить" строку хотите, а не соответствия найти/проверить.

```
$txt = 'Хочу пить!<img src="/images/upload/3k0tx90veagw88gsgwwoocgk8sg4k8w.png"/>Хочу,< и пить!<img src="/images/upload/gidykcwjge0wwcs8ws40kw4040sw44w.png"/>Хочу: есть?';

$data = preg_split("/(<img.*?>)/", $txt, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($data);
```

результат:

```
[0] => Хочу пить!
[1] => <img src="/images/upload/3k0tx90veagw88gsgwwoocgk8sg4k8w.png"/>
[2] => Хочу,< и пить!
[3] => <img src="/images/upload/gidykcwjge0wwcs8ws40kw4040sw44w.png"/>
[4] => Хочу: есть?
```

Comment: ему видимо тестовое задание именно с функцией прег_матч))

Answer (score 0):

> Вариант с разделением текста и картинок по отдельным массивам:

```
$str = 'Хочу пить!<img src="/images/upload/3k0tx90veagw88gsgwwoocgk8sg4k8w.png"/>Хочу,< и пить!<img src="/images/upload/gidykcwjge0wwcs8ws40kw4040sw44w.png"/>Хочу: есть?';

$patt = "~(?<=^|/>)(?'txt'.+?)(?=<img|$)|(?'img'<img[^>]+>)~iu";
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $a);

$txt = array_filter($a['txt']);
$img = array_filter($a['img']);
```

> Результаты:

```
print_r($txt);
Array
(
    [0] => Хочу пить!
    [2] => Хочу,< и пить!
    [4] => Хочу: есть?
)

print_r($img);
Array
(
    [1] => <img src="/images/upload/3k0tx90veagw88gsgwwoocgk8sg4k8w.png"/>
    [3] => <img src="/images/upload/gidykcwjge0wwcs8ws40kw4040sw44w.png"/>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример регулярки который ищет в группах то что вам нужно.

```
#(((?!\<img).)*)(\<img.[^>]*\>)(((?!\<img).)*)#gs
```

А [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/OkxiF7/1) можете проверить работу регулярки